# Excel Graph x-axis spacing

Tags: excel

[image]

I have the following situation. I am trying to use the top row (row 1) as the scale of the graph, and want to use the 2nd row as the data. The problem is, it does not use the top row as a scale, just as another data set. I have tried modifying the x-axis values:

[image]

but this does not scale the x-axis at all to what I want (which would be a linear relationship).

Comment: Question should really have been on super user.  Its more about how to graph with excel than to program or use complex formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of graph from a line plot or line graph to a scatter plot.  A line graph just takes each entry in the series as an integer and augments the integer for the next point by one.  It completely ignores what the values of the X part of the series is.

A scatter XY plot will take into consideration what the X values for the series are and space them out accordingly.

All you need to do is change your graph type.

Comment: Excellent answer. Cheers